# JRE randomly disappears

Tags: windows, jre

When I start up my computer, everything works fine. However, if it runs for a while and I try to open Eclipse (which I can open fine initially), I get the "Java Runtime Environment Needed... No Java virtual machine was found after searching following locations" error message. After I restart everything works fine for a while.

I'm also having the same problem when trying to access environment variables through the start menu - Windows error popup stating cannot find SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe type message.

Has anyone ever run into something like this before or have any insight on it?

Thanks

EDIT: Seems programs also cannot find rundll32.exe, even though it's right there in Windows\System32

Comment: If you open a command window, what's the output of `echo %PATH%` ?

Comment: Make sure you have a current backup.  Your disk drive may be failing.

Comment: @Darth Android when I first start up, path contains all of the pathnames, but after I run into this issue it only shows a couple.

Comment: @Harry Johnston is there any test I could run that could check if it is indeed failing?

Comment: @alex28: I have no particular recommendation, check the web site of the disk drive's manufacturer.  But it looks as though Darth Android has identified the problem correctly (a failing disk drive would not be likely to affect your PATH) so apart from making sure you have a current backup I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet you have a program that's destroying your `%PATH%` then. If you can get the issue to crop up fairly regularly, then periodically re-run the command after starting programs you use normally and during normal use to see when the path is mangled, and try to correlate that to which program might be doing it.

The `%PATH%` environment variable is used to resolve where executables are located on the system, so if entries are removed from it, then certain things, like `java` and and `rundll32` can no longer be found.

Basically, when anything tells the OS to run "java.exe", the OS splits the Path variable on `;` (windows) or `:` (linux) to create a list of folders, and then checks each one of those folders to see if it contains an executable named `java.exe`. The problem is if you (or a program) removes the folder that holds the java executable from the path, then windows can't find it.

I would look especially hard at what the remaining paths are in `%PATH%` after it gets mangled - you might have a program that is trying to add itself to the path, but fails to include the previous entries, which means the culprit may be related to one of the paths left.

Comment: I *think* the issue was that the path variable was right up against the 2047 character limit, and any modifications to it messed the entire thing up. I created a bunch of shortcuts for the longest path names and that seems to have done the trick.